# Exclude given objects from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have the below array. I am attempting to exclude certain objects from this array in processing.

For example. I would like to exclude the type 'dog' and only use any object that is of type duck.

I'd like to do this using underscore/lodash but will use plain JS if need be.

```
animals: [
  {
    type: 'duck',
    name: 'quack',
  },
  {
    type: 'duck',
    name: 'quieck',
  },
  {
    type: 'dog',
    name: 'bark',
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Underscore/LoDash way, would be just

```
var result = _.where(animals, {type: 'duck'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your array represents variable `animals`. You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. If you want all ducks:

```
const animals = [
    { type: 'duck', name: 'quack' },
    { type: 'duck', name: 'quieck' },
    { type: 'dog', name: 'bark' },
];
const ducks = animals.filter(o => o.type === 'duck');
```

or if you want to exclude all dogs:

```
const withoutDogs = animals.filter(o => o.type !== 'dog');
```

I used ES6 syntax. ES5 equivalent would be:

```
var ducks = animals.filter(function(o) { return o.type === 'duck' });
```